# How do I create a batch file to move certain file extensions to another folder?

Tags: batch-file, file-io, file-extension

Basically I need to make a batch file that moves (not copies) files with certain file extensions (namely .jpg, .jpeg, .png and .gif) to another folder. I've tried a few different things I found on this website and other websites but I'm awful at this sort of thing so it hasn't seemed to work. So please feel free to explain it like you're explaining it to someone totally new at programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
for %%o in (.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif) do move "*%%o" "another folder"
```